# Why can't some traits be made into objects

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I understand [the rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html) for when a trait can be made into a trait object, but I don't understand *why* these rules exist.

For example:

```rust
trait Resource {
    const RESOURCE_ID: u64;
}

trait ResourceStatic {
    fn static_id() -> u64;
}

trait ResourceInstance {
    fn resource_id(&self) -> u64;
}

struct MyResource {}

impl Resource for MyResource {
    const RESOURCE_ID: u64 = 123;
}

impl ResourceStatic for MyResource {
    fn static_id() -> u64 {
        123
    }
}

impl ResourceInstance for MyResource {
    fn resource_id(&self) -> u64 {
        123
    }
}
```

It seems to me all three traits are basically encapsulating the same functionality. Why is it then that these are not allowed:

```rust
let _: Box<dyn Resource> = Box::new(MyResource{});
let _: Box<dyn ResourceStatic> = Box::new(MyResource{});
```

but this is?

```rust
let _: Box<dyn ResourceInstance> = Box::new(MyResource{});
```

Can someone please explain what is going on under the hood so that it doesn't seem arbitrary?

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b617ae5bad55319217fdffa7677a5f3b)

Comment: How do you know which type to fetch a constant or call a method on? You have to have the object pointer, so ResourceInstance is the only one of those traits that is usable as a Trait Object.

Comment: @user1937198 why can't there be object pointers for the other traits?

Comment: my point is, for a ResourceStatic, what can you do with an object pointer to it that you can't do with an empty trait? Its making that uselessness explicit that object safety is about.

Comment: @user1937198 ah, so it's just a matter of enforcing code cleanliness?

Comment: Mostly explicitness. Although in the case of constants I suspect there is a certian amount of leaving the design space open for future work.

Comment: @user1937198 I see, thank you! Do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: I'm not solid enough on it being an official reasoning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is a trait object? It is

- a **value**,
- of a concrete type **not known to the compiler**,
- which nevertheless **implements a trait**.

This definition is sufficient to explain why `ResourceInstance` works while `Resource` and `ResourceStatic` don't.

#### `ResourceInstance`

```
trait ResourceInstance {
    fn resource_id(&self) -> u64;
}
```

This trait can be made into an object because even when the **concrete type is not known**, you can still call `resource_id` on a **value that implements the trait** (by passing it as the `self` parameter).

#### `ResourceStatic`

```
trait ResourceStatic {
    fn static_id() -> u64;
}
```

This trait cannot be made into an object, because `static_id` can be called **without a value**, which means in order to call `static_id` you must **know the concrete type**.

For each trait object type (e.g. `dyn ResourceStatic`), the compiler automatically generates an implementation of the corresponding trait (`ResourceStatic`). This automatic implementation uses the vtable pointer passed as part of the `self` type in the trait methods. When there is no `self` type there is no vtable pointer and the compiler can't automatically implement that method. There are no "bare vtable pointers" in Rust.

To perhaps understand this better, imagine `dyn ResourceStatic` is a valid type. What does `<dyn ResourceStatic>::static_id()` do? It cannot defer to the implementation of the concrete type, because there is no value and therefore no concrete type. Shall we conclude that `dyn ResourceStatic` *doesn't implement* `ResourceStatic`? That seems obviously wrong. Or does `dyn ResourceStatic` have its own implementation of `ResourceStatic` that *doesn't* defer to some concrete type? That also doesn't make sense, because the whole point of `dyn ResourceStatic` is to stand in for a concrete type.

The way Rust resolves this problem is simply to reject `dyn ResourceStatic` as a type.

#### `Resource`

```
trait Resource {
    const RESOURCE_ID: u64;
}
```

This trait cannot be made into an object for the same reason `ResourceStatic` cannot: because it's impossible for the trait object type `dyn Resource` to automatically satisfy the requirements of the trait.

### TL;DR

If you want dynamic dispatch on the type `Self`, you need a `self` argument to dispatch on.